# How to share my linux folder with mac mini over nfs

Tags: unix, nfs, mac

I tried to mount using following command after exporting the folder in linux source machine ( NFS server)  .

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw 192.168.12.10:/home/pavunkumar  /private/nfs
```

It is mounted successfully in my mac mini. I could see using mount -v

```
192.168.12.10:/home/pavunkumar on /private/nfs (nfs)
```

But, when I tried to get into that directory , I am getting error as follows

```
Mac-mini-5:~ pavunkumar$ cd /private/nfs/
-bash: cd: /private/nfs/: Permission denied
Mac-mini-5:~ pavunkumar$
```

When I check the permission, it is in following mode

```
drwx------  101 1014  _lpoperator  16384 Aug 27 16:12 nfs
```

Do I need to change permission explicitly for each time ?

Comment: Check the permissions.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different uids for the users on the Linux and the MacOS machine, so you run into issues with the permissions.

Either change the users to have the same ID (or use something like NIS or LDAP as backend) or set the permission of the shared directory to allow access for everyone.

Comment: +1 , Yes I got it now. Why down vote for me ?